# clarity in the solution of the following problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, problem-solving, constants

$$(D^2+D)y=x^2+2x+4$$

I found the solution as $$CF=C_{1}+e^{-x}C_{2}$$ and PI=$$\left(\frac{x^3}{3}\right)+4x$$

but the solution from my teacher is PI = $$\left(\frac{x^3}{3}\right)+4x+C3$$

Where This extra C3 is from, Is the solution right If I exclude the C3 ?

Comment: Do you mean $CF = C_{1} + C_{2}e^{-x} $?

Comment: Derivative and second derivative of constant $C_3$ is zero.

Comment: @john yes i mean that

Comment: There is no need of the $C_3$.

Comment: You can't have 3 constants in a linear second order ODE